# mysqli testing to see if connection to server is made and if specific database located

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

```
<?php
    mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password") or die("Couldn't connect to the database!");
    mysqli_select_db("registration_system") or die("Couldn't find database!"); 
?>
```

Above is the code i'm using to see if the connections to my server has been made the password i input is the same as my phpmyadmin password. The code is saved in a file called connect.php which is included to my header.php file which is then included in my index.php using "". I have no idea why it isn't working and i keep getting this error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045):
>   Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   /home/a7430557/public_html/inc/connect.inc.php on line 2

Couldn't connect to the database!

Comment: You can't use `root` to connect on your server. Are you using cPanel?

Comment: ye i think so im using 000webhost

Comment: You'll need to create an account as you can't use root.

Comment: I'm sorry create an account where?

Comment: On the cpanel in your 000webhost. [**Read This**](http://stvcstvc.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/how-to-setup-mysql-database-in-000webhost-com/)

Comment: I already have an account on there it's still giving me the same error

Comment: Your are referring to the username and password in the account information section when you navigate to cpanel

Comment: No, that's your account login. You **need** to create a **mysql user**.